# Two word verbs with adverb

Tags: verbs, adverbs

I was just working on a Chinese review app and came across the sentence:

他游泳游得很快。

And I was wondering if the doubling of the first character is unique to certain kinds of verbs or all 2 character verbs.

Or can I also say 他游泳得很快。?

Comment: grammar topic: **complement of degree 程度补语** with **object 宾语** ，cf. ＂外国人实用汉语语法＂position of the object 宾语的位置（１）要是动词谓语后面同时带宾语和程度补语，一定要 **重复动词** ，程度补语要放在重复的动词后边，助词＂得＂则要放在的动词程度补语之间。order is as follows: 动词谓语___宾语___重复的动词谓语___＂得＂（助词）___程度补语。例如：回答问题回答得很完全。打行李打得很结实。种树种得不多。additional topic: **离合词** separable verbs, e.g. 游泳 where 泳 is a noun as well as a verb: swimming, to swim, so that 游泳 can be considered a verb-object verb, and 游泳游得很快 follows above rule for complements of degree with object

Comment: ＂现代汉语离合词＂（supporting comment #1): 游泳。。。 **［误］** 你游泳得很好 **［正］** （１）你游泳游得很好（２）你游得很好

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with comment 1 & 2.

游泳 is **Separable Word**(离合词). There are some other 离合词: 吃饭， 睡觉， 散步， etc.

The grammar here is that 离合词 can not be followed with an object or a complement directly.

1. Followed by an object, it has to add a prep word. For example, 我和他见面， not 我见面他. Unlike in English, where we can say **I met him**, but not **I met with him**.
2. Followed by a complement, it should repeat the verb character out of 离合词( 游 is a verb character out of 游泳 in this case). So, the correct phrasing of your sentence should be 他游泳**游**得很快.  More examples : 他吃饭吃得很慢; 他跑步跑得很快; 他结婚结得很草率; 游泳，吃饭，跑步 and 结婚 are all 离合词(separable word).

You should also note that **not all two-character verbs** are separable(离合词), hence follows the rules above.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly just for clarity rather than anything else.

他游泳得很快 is not okay but 他游得很快 is okay. Without any context though who could understand a random `他游得很快`? No one, really. Hence we get our doubling up: 他游泳游得很快。